# htaccess 301 redirect page url to another page

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Can I use htaccess to get values from the input url and change it in the redirection example:

```
 www.example.com/cars-minneapolis-mn/
```

redirect to

```
 www.example.com/cool-suv-auto-in-minneapolis-mn/
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your attempts.

Comment: I tried a manual attemp but I have many pages Redirect 301 /cars-minneapolis-mn/ http://www.example.com/cool-suv-auto-in-minneapolis-mn/

Comment: Exactly how do these URLs map from one to the other? In your example, you appear to replace the word "cars" with "cool-suv-auto-in" - is that a general mapping you want to apply to all URLs? Does the word "cars" always appear at the start of the URL-path? You need to first clearly define the rules (in natural language) that map the URLs from one to the other.

Comment: cool-suv-auto-in is constant but the minneapolis-mn should be from the input url

Answer (score 0):

you can try with many ways here is one:

```
RedirectMatch "^/cars-minneapolis-mn\/?$" "http://example.com/cool-suv-auto-in-minneapolis-mn/"
```

this will redirect your existing url to new url